# windows device encrypts when joined to azure active directory

Tags: azure-activedirectory

Windows devices are getting encrypted with bitlocker when I join them to Azure active directory.

Is there a setting when joining new windows devices to azure AD that automatically encrypts the hard drive and can it be disabled?

Comment: “Is there a setting when joining new windows devices to azure AD that automatically encrypts the hard drive and can it be disabled?” - Yes; It’s likely a device enrollment policy setup by your system Administrator. It can be disabled by your system administrator

Comment: I cannot find any policy that is requiring encryption.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/encrypt-devices) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-group-policy-settings)

Comment: I have reviewed those and encryption is not required.

Comment: Is BitLocker being enabled after enrollment into a Azure AD a problem you actually face? Have you asked your IT administrator?

Comment: I have devices with encryption enabled (not bitlocker) and I do not want to join these devices and have bitlocker try and encrypt them too.

Comment: I think this maybe the laptops themselves encrypting automatically once I use a microsoft account. they are dell latitude laptops. https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ie/000124701/automatic-windows-device-encryption-bitlocker-on-dell-systems#:~:text=Click%20the%20Start%20button%2C%20select,back%20up%20your%20recovery%20key.

Answer (score 0):

laptop was not being encrypted by any intune policy. it was automatically encrypted once a microsoft account was used. see this link from Dell - [https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ie/000124701/automatic-windows-device-encryption-bitlocker-on-dell-systems#:~:text=Click%20the%20Start%20button%2C%20select,back%20up%20your%20recovery%20key](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ie/000124701/automatic-windows-device-encryption-bitlocker-on-dell-systems#:%7E:text=Click%20the%20Start%20button%2C%20select,back%20up%20your%20recovery%20key).